# Mapstruct - mapping field using a mathematical formula (e.g. target="x", source="a+b")

Tags: mapstruct

I am using mapstrcut to map my entities to dto, I am now facing a problem that in the DTO there is an extra field which is "discount", and I need mapstruct to manage filling this field, and this field is calculated based on 2 values (salePrice and retailPrice).

My question how can I do this kind of mapping like using mapstruct.

```
@Mapping(target="discount", source="retailPrice-salePrice")
```

When I tried adding this line the code break while building says:

```
 error: No property named "salePrice*retailPrice" exists in source parameter(s).
            @Mapping(source="salePrice*retailPrice", target="discount")
```

So How can I do such mapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the feature of [Java expressions](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#expressions) for situations like this:

```
@Mapping( target="discount", expression="java( source.getRetailPrice() - source.getSalePrice())" )
```

The given "expression" will be added to the generated code as is. You may add additional imports to the generated class via `@Mapper#imports()` if needed.

We've (very vague) plans for supporting an actual scripting language for expressions like this, but we are not there yet :)

Comment: @Gunnar, is there a way to call a method with custom logic for calculating a field?

Comment: The example above is exactly showing this: within `expression` you can specify whatever Java call you may need.

Comment: It's not just expression. It will have many number of lines of code in some cases. It isn't readable to put all that logic in an annotation.In dozer, we have custom converters for executing logic. I need something smiliar in mapstruct. I've gone through the documentation. I couldn't find as such.

Comment: You could just implement this method in a hand-written method (declared on the same mapper if it is an abstract class or on a _used mapper_ class otherwise) and invoke that one.

Comment: @Gunnar Any plans for adding feature to support mappign immutable objects?